# libvirt-kvm and libvirt shows up as login profiles on Kubuntu 23.04

Tags: kubuntu, login, virtualization, qemu

Last night, I want to install Qemu on my Kubuntu 23.04.
I found this article to follow along to install Qemu on my computer:

1. [Install and Use Qemu on Ubuntu](https://itsfoss.com/qemu-ubuntu/)

After reboot my pc, I notice `libvirt-kvm` and `libvirt` shows up as users you can login onto my computer:

[image: users]

I have done some research and I found this post Primary Groups vs. Supplement/Secondary Groups:

1. [Primary vs secondary groups in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/605531/primary-vs-secondary-groups-in-linux)

I am assuming `libvirt` and `libvirt-kvm` are added in my ***Primary Group***.

Is this a ***MUST*** to have QEMU work properly on my PC?

if not, Is there a way for `libvirt` and `libvirt-kvm` users' profile not show up as login options?

Comment: Interesting... the tutorial you linked says *"To make Qemu work, you'd have to add your user to two groups: libvirt-kvm and libvirt"* but AFAIK that's simply not what those commands do - even the link it provides in support says to use either `adduser` or `usermod` **not** `useradd`

Comment: @steeldriver Do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial that you linked says:

> To make Qemu work, you'd have to add your user to two groups: libvirt-kvm and libvirt.
>
> To do so, use the following commands one by one:
>
> ```
> sudo useradd -g $USER libvirt
>
> sudo useradd -g $USER libvirt-kvm
> ```

However those commands **do not** add a user to a group - as you have discovered, they *create* two new users, with their primary group (`-g`) name equal to the username of the invoking user. On Ubuntu, that happens to succeed because such a group exists by default (it is the user's *private group*). Since they are created as non-system users (UID > 1000) they show up in the display manager.

The link provided in the tutorial suggests two **correct** ways to add a user to a group: `sudo adduser username groupname` and `sudo usermod -a -G group_name username`. So for example:

```
sudo adduser "$USER" libvirt
sudo adduser "$USER" libvirt-kvm
```

or

```
sudo usermod -a -G libvirt "$USER"
sudo usermod -a -G libvirt-kvm "$USER"
```

**however I'm not sure these are necessary - I'd suggest seeking out a more reliable tutorial**.

Fortunately (at least with the default Ubuntu `/etc/default/useradd`) the commands that you were instructed to use may be undone fairly easily:

```
sudo userdel libvirt
sudo userdel libvirt-kvm
```